# "state" -- when is it a countable or uncountable noun?

Tags: articles, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

Example with a context ([Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28abstract_data_type%29)):

> A stack may be implemented to have a bounded capacity. If the stack is full and does not contain enough space to accept an entity to be pushed, the stack is then considered to be **in an overflow state**. The pop operation removes an item from the top of the stack. A pop either reveals previously concealed items or results in an empty stack, but, if the stack is empty, it goes **into underflow state**, which means no items are present in stack to be removed.

Could you please explain when we should use the word *state* with an article (countable noun) and when with no article (mass noun)? The meaning of the word *state* that I'm referring to here, of course, has to do with a particular condition that something is in at a specific time as in the usage example above that talks about software objects such as stacks that can change their state during their lifetime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Into underflow state" here is simply a mistake. It should have an article: "into AN underflow state".

"State", in the sense of "condition or status", is a countable noun, period.

Answer (score 2):

You do not use articles before nouns if they describe a type and not an instance.

> if the stack is empty, it goes into underflow state

The writer here is saying that *underflow* is a type of state that the stack can be in.  In a programming context, this has the implication that the stack can be in one of several well-defined states, such as "underflow", "normal", "overflow", "disabled", for example.

Saying *an underflow state* would make *underflow* no longer a state that can be "labeled" upon the stack, and we are no longer making the implication there is an enumeration of states for the stack.